# Error al verificar registro

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Mi problema es al verificar si hay un registro en la base de datos

```
$category_id = $_POST["category_id"]; 
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $created_at = date('Y-m-d');

    $veri = "SELECT count(*) FROM medic WHERE name = '$name' ";
    $result = $db->select($veri); 
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    $user_count = $row[0];
    if($user_count>0) {echo "1";}
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO medic (name, lastname, email, address, phone, created_at, category_id) VALUES  ('$name',
                     '$lastname',
                     '$email',
                     '$address',
                     '$phone',
                     '$created_at',
                     '$category_id')";
        $r = $db->select($query);
        echo "Datos Insertado";
    }
```

Me da el fallo:

> "Trying to get property of non-object in" 
>   No tengo ni idea de lo que puede estar fallando

Comment: Si imprimes $row[0] qué te imprime?

Comment: ¿Estás usando `PDO` o `mysqli`? Coloca por favor el texto completo del error.  Me parece que ni la clase `PDO`, ni la clase `mysqli` definen un método `select`.  Por otra parte, el código es vulnerable a inyección de código `SQL` ya que no hace una verificación de los valores tomados de `$POST` antes de integrarlos en el comando `SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar un alias en la consulta.

Prueba cambiando:

```
$veri = "SELECT count(*) FROM medic WHERE name = '$name' ";
```

por:

```
$veri = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM medic WHERE name = '$name' ";
```

Después obtienes el valor así:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$user_count = $row["total"];
```

Comment: En todo caso también necesita un fetch_assoc.

Comment: Sí, correcto. ;)

Comment: En todo caso no creo que eso arregle su problema. La implementación de fetch_row que hace él es correcta. Tal vez ni siquiera le esté regresando valor esa consulta, por eso le pedí que nos mostrara qué valor tiene $row[0]. También puede que sea que necesite concatenar bien la variable. $veri = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM medic WHERE name = '".$name."'"; Tal vez y ni siquiera el input se llama 'name' haha. Vamos a esperar qué nos comenta.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás usando `fetch_row` supongo que estás usando `mysqli`. En ese caso, te comento que no existe el método `select` para mysqli. (Tampoco para PDO en realidad)

Donde dice

```
$result = $db->select($veri);
```

Debiese decir

```
$result = $db->query($veri);
```

De lo contrario estarás asignando un valor nulo a $result, y tratar de ejecutar el método `fetch_row` sobre algo que no es un objeto te tira el error que estás viendo.

Arreglado lo anterior, vas a tener un segundo problema donde haces

```
$r = $db->select($query);
```

Cuando en realidad debiera ser

```
$r = $db->query($query);
```